# Why are two Excel sheets opening when I try to create one in VBscript?

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I have written a program in VBscript to create an excel sheet. The program works fine, and when i click on the Excel sheet to open it, the sheet i created is opened as well as a new excel "Book1". Why is this happening? How can I stop it so that only the sheet i created will open? 
Code is given below:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")            'Bind to the Excel object
objExcel.Workbooks.Add                                      'Create a new workbook.
Sheet = 1                                                   'Select the first sheet
Set objSheet = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet)    'Bind to worksheet. 
objSheet.Name = "InfoBook"                                  'Name the worksheet
strExcelPath = "c:\scripts\InfoBook.xlsx"                   'Set the save location

objSheet.Range("A1:C1").Font.Bold = True
objExcel.Columns(3).AutoFit()
objSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Date"                         'Row 1 Column 1 (A)
objSheet.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Time"                         'Row 1 Column 2 (B)
objSheet.Cells(1, 3).Value = "Category"                     'Row 1 Column 3 (C)

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs strExcelPath
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
objExcel.Application.Quit
```

Comment: Does this same thing happen when you open any other workbook? Nothing in your code will affect what happens once you close excel and then open a specific file as that code will not be perpetuated in your created workbook.

Comment: I just did this basic same code and it happened to me too. With no Excel open I opened the newlycreated book and it opened TWO workbooks, one was called Book2 and then there was the target book. Strange.

Comment: @nbayly its happening only when i open workbooks i've created using vbs..

Comment: I think it's something to do with the objExcel.Workbooks.Add, is there no way to add a new workbook with a name as opposed to declaring the name when you save it. You need to rewrite this code without using "ActiveWorkbook" Make a new objWorkbook and `set` it with your new name, then use the object to manipulate it and save it

Comment: I didn't try this in vbscript, but it seems to me that when you create the objexcel object, excel will open with a new workbook automatically.  Then when you execute the objexcel.workbooks.add line, a second new book is created.   You do your thing, and then when you close the "target" book, you are left with the original book1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem is. The line

```
objSheet.Name = "InfoBook"
```

creates a workbook with that name. Then when we specify the path for the workbook, we are again creating a workbook of that name in the following line

```
strExcelPath = "c:\scripts\InfoBook.xlsx"
```

so the trick is to only name the excel workbook in the path, so it'll only be opened once, and saved where we want it.

Thanks to everyone who spent time on this little predicament of mine. Hope it helped you guys too.

Comment: That **shouldn't** be the problem - `objSheet.Name` is the name of the `Worksheet`, but the path is specifying the name you will save the `Workbook` as.  (A `Workbook` is an Excel file, a `Worksheet` or `Sheet` is a "tab" within the file.)

Comment: @YowE3K the objSheet.Name line is naming an excel sheet. When the excel workbook is opened, one is my target, named "Infobook" and the other one is the default "Book1". However, in Book1, Sheet1 has been renamed to "Infobook". But in "Infobook", Sheet1 is not renamed as anything. Thats what caused the problem, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried rebooting your computer and running the code again?

The additional workbook may be left over from an earlier, failed, attempt at running the code.  Although I cannot replicate the error using just your posted code, I can replicate it by performing

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")            'Bind to the Excel object
objExcel.Workbooks.Add                                      'Create a new workbook.
```

and **then** running your script.

Because the first script creates a workbook **but doesn't close the Excel application**, when you open the workbook created by your script, the still running instance of Excel is opened (which still contains Book1) and your workbook is also opened.

Rebooting your computer will get rid of the running instance of Excel - or you can just terminate it using Task Manager.

Comment: rebooting the computer doesn't help either. Also, I don't know any other way to create an excel sheet using vbs. Do you know another way?

Comment: @krishna - If the problem persisted after rebooting the computer, then the issue isn't being caused by another instance of Excel being open in the background.  (Well, I guess it **could** be, if you had a Startup script that was opening Excel, but that is highly unlikely.)  I don't know of another way to create an Excel workbook using vbs and, as I said, your script works for me in its current state - it only does weird things if I force an instance of Excel to be still open in the background when I try to open the created workbook.

Comment: I figured out what the problem was. I've posted the answer here as well

Comment: @krishna - That may be something that should be easy to check - open Task Manager before running your script and make sure that the Excel.exe process is not running, and then watch while you run the script - it should appear in the list of processes, and then disappear when your script gets to the `Application.Quit` statement.